# Close both dialog windows using first dialog's close icon

Tags: jquery

I have a dialog window that contains a link that opens an other dialog window. What I want to do is to close them both when user click on first dialog's close icon.

```
<script>        

var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $JQ_(function(){
    $JQ_('[id^="dialog"]').dialog({autoOpen:false,
                                      width:'auto',
                                     height:'auto',
                                  resizable:false,
                                       show:{effect:"fade", duration:250},
                                       hide:{effect:"fade", duration:250},
                                       });
    $JQ_("#opener_0").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_0").dialog("open");});
    $JQ_("#opener_1").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog("open");});
    });

</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle example... [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/w5YLR/)

Comment: Simply use the close _event_ of the first to call the close _method_ of the second one …

Comment: Any example my friend?

Comment: create a fiddle please

Comment: Here is your fiddle... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/w5YLR/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
$JQ_("#dialog_0").on('dialogclose', function() {
    $JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog('close');
});
```

SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/w5YLR/1/

Comment: No I don't think so... Please take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/w5YLR/)